# C# Compare two ordered lists for updated values added

Tags: c#, list, overlap

I have a data source containing say, 6 items, order important, which updates each time I check it. 

Here is the initial list

**List 1:**

- dog
- cat
- fish
- cat
- cat
- mouse

I then wait, the list updates some amount with the top items being removed and new ones added. Here is the new list I fetch.
**List 2:**

- fish
- cat
- cat
- mouse
- **cat**
- **hamster**

I would like a way of finding out the new values which were added, cat + hamster in this case.

My actual problem has a source of 38 items and each check, between 0 - 38 items have been added to the bottom. I cannot view any more than the latest 38 items however.

**Example**

```
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

        list1.Add("dog");
        list1.Add("cat");
        list1.Add("fish");
        list1.Add("cat");
        list1.Add("cat");
        list1.Add("mouse");

        list2.Add("fish");
        list2.Add("cat");
        list2.Add("cat");
        list2.Add("mouse");
        list2.Add("cat");
        list2.Add("hamster");

        Console.WriteLine("List 1" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach(string item in list1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "List 2" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (string item in list2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        var newItems = list2.Except(list1);

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "New Items" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (string item in newItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Using Except, the result is 'hamster' as cat did exist in the first list and except does not seem to check order (Is there a way?)

Now, this seems easy and like it should have been answered so I presume I'm just not typing the right thing into search.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**
I can imagine a solution by looping through lists of increasing size, starting with the last value of list 1 and the first value of list 2 and then using SequenceEqual() until false to count how many items overlap and going from there.
Would this be a good solution?

**Solution Used**
I did as mentioned in my edit and looped through comparing lists of increasing size for a match using SequenceEqual()

Im sure this is inefficient but this wont pose as issue for me. If anyone does know a neater trick, that would be great.

```
        int size1 = list1.Count();
        int size2 = list2.Count();

        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= size2; i++)
        {
            List<string> aList = list1.GetRange(size1 - i, i);
            List<string> bList = list2.GetRange(0, i);
            if(aList.SequenceEqual(bList))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        int totalAdded = size2 - i;
        List<string> newItemsList = list2.GetRange(i, totalAdded);

        foreach (string item in newItemsList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: So you mean your list is ordered? I mean, your list1 has 3 cats and your list2 has 3 cats too but in anouther order. is the order important? why don't you use a primary key?

Comment: You should try out your edit.

Comment: How do you know that "cat" and "hamster" were the only things added to the list? If someone added (dog dog fish cat cat mouse cat hamster), you'd get the same results, right?

Comment: What will you do if your new items just repeating your old items (with new values maybe): e.g. initial list: `dogcatfishdogcatfish` loaded list `dogcatfishdogcatfish`? Just as @StriplingWarrior has pointed out..

Comment: You cannot rely on the data you given only, as the guys said, i can add 6 more items as dog cat fish cat cat mouse, then in this case you cannot tell what are the new entries, you need other criteria for example the datetime was added then it will be easy.

Comment: Hi, yes, if in the case of all the items being added again, this would pose an issue. In my actual problem, 38 items are recorded an the chanced of a direct repeat of all 38 is impossibly low.

Comment: I have now solved as in the edit, I am not sure it is the best solution but it seems to work. Will post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to create a third list with the new items? Or at least find the new items:

```
List<string> newItems = new List<string>();
newItems.AddRange(list2.FindAll(s=> !list1.Contains(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that StriplingWarrior mentioned in the comment is very important. Although its possibility is low, but the solution should be the one that works in all cases.

I recommend you to change your data structure and add **an integer** next to your entities. The integer is called **ID** or **Key** which shows the difference between cat with ID = 3 and cat with ID = 7. so you will never get confused about which cat you are looking for.

The best structure for the new structure is called **Dictionary**.

I changed your code below, which results **cat** and **hamster**:

```
        int incrementalID = 0;
        Dictionary<int, string> list1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, string> list2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "dog");    //ID = 0
        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "cat");     //ID = 1
        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "fish");    //ID = 2
        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "cat");     //ID = 3
        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "cat");     //ID = 4
        list1.Add(incrementalID++, "mouse");   //ID = 5

        list2 = new Dictionary<int, string>(list1);
        list2.Remove(0);
        list2.Remove(1);
        list2.Add(incrementalID++, "cat");      //ID = 6
        list2.Add(incrementalID++, "hamster");  //ID = 7;

        Console.WriteLine("List 1" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (string item in list1.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "List 2" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (string item in list2.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        var newItems = list2.Except(list1);

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "New Items" + Environment.NewLine);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in newItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
```

Comment: was this answer usefull?